# PHPDoc container objects to act like arrays

Tags: php, phpstorm, phpdoc

Is it possible to indicate that an object behaves like a container, implements `\ArrayAccess` when writing a doc, specifically, a `@return` one.

For example if I have a `class Collection implements \ArrayAccess, \Countable, \IteratorAggregate` object filled with `Entity` objects from database.

What I'd like to have is `PHPStorm` (specifically) to have hints available for `Collection` objects as well as to understand what values they have.

Currently we have this notation for arrays of objects

```
/**
* @return \Entity[]
*/
```

This means the method returns an array of Entities. How may I do the same for a different class? I'm thinking about something like this:

```
/**
* @return \Entity[\Collection]
*/
```

I have created a [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/SCj5MU2G) (note that it has links to two more pastebins for `Entity` and `Collection` classes).

[PASTEBIN example](http://pastebin.com/SCj5MU2G)

Comment: Could you please clarify what you want to achieve with `\Entity[\Collection]` (in other words: what it means for you).

Comment: @LazyOne sorry for not being clear. That means that the return value is a collection consisting of multiple entities. Just like `\Entity[]` currently means the return value is an array consisting of multiple entities.

Comment: So basically ... it's Collection and array of Entities at the same time, right? If so -- have you tried `\Collection|\Entity[]` syntax? That's the only one I can think of right now.

Comment: Right. That's basically an `OR` statement, looks interesting, but PHPStorm autocompletes only for the first mentioned class, in this case, the \Collection :(

Comment: Could you please create and share some sample project (or just single file) with basic implementation that would illustrate your situation (basic implementation of your Collection and Entity classes and how you use them )? Projects which I'm involved (usually 3-5+ years old) do not use any collections (or proper ORM at all) so I do not have anything at hand to quickly check other options.

Comment: @LazyOne I have edited the question and added example code, please note it was stripped of some stuff so something may not work if you'll try to execute it. And thanks for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Based on your pastebin examples** single typehint in right place seems to be enough (tested in PhpStorm v9.5 EAP build):

```
/** @var \Collection|\Entity[] $collection */
$collection = new Collection($entities);
```

For `$collection` it offers methods from `\Collection` class:

[image]

For `$entity` (inside foreach loop) it offers `\Entity` methods:

[image]

If anything you can always type hint `$entity` variable individually:

[image]

Comment: That's what I was looking for, strange, but I tried `/** @var \Collection|\Entity[] $collection */` yesterday and it did not work, maybe it was because phpstorm was still parsing the code. However, I've just tried adding `/* @method \EntityCollection|\Entity\Client[] findAll($filter) */` and indeed, it does everything perfectly. I still don't understand how it's working though, and how PHPStorm understands that it's an instance of collection that is returned in the first place. Anyway it works as `@method` return value and I thank you very much for this.

Answer (score 1):

What you seem to want cannot really be done (at the moment) as far as I am aware. I've tried to get the same functionality myself some time ago.

However, you can do something like this:

```
<?php

/**
 * @return MyCollectionType
 */
function getEntityCollectionFromSomewhere()
{
    return ...
}

$myEntityCollection = getEntityCollectionFromSomewhere();

foreach($myEntityCollection as $entity)
{
    if ($entity instanceof MyEntityType)
    {
        // code completion is active here for MyEntityType...
    }
}
```

This is the best I've found so far; you get Collection completion where you're working with a collection, and entity functionality where you're working with a single element from that collection.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't see why autocomplete for collection should fire here, are you sure it's not `@return Collection`?

Comment: And does PHPStorm start to typehint `MyEntityType` because of the `if` statement?

Comment: @SergeyTelshevsky: you are correct, I'll fix my mistake in the code sample. and yes the `if instanceof ...` construct lets PHPStorm understand your intention and enables the code completion there.

Comment: also `/* @var $entity Entity */` and it makes it clear it's just there for the type hinting

Comment: @Alfwed: Indeed, if you like. I just find the `instanceof` check easier on my eyes. (I don't like comments to have actual program meaning)

Comment: Thank you very much, but I don't really like the fact that I have to go all `inline` and prepend a comment everywhere I use it, so @LazyOne 's solution is the better one for me!